# AAC Audio in JW Player

Tags: jwplayer

I am using JW Player to play streaming audio from a SHOUTcast server. The audio is HE-AAC V2. It works in Chrome, but not Internet Explorer, Firefox or Safari. I get an error that says "Error Loading Media: File not found".

In Chrome, it only works in HTML5 as the primary. If it gets switched to Flash, it stops.

I am using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player1234').setup({
        file: 'http://s2.radioreformation.com:8004/;stream.aac',
        image: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/radioreformation/playerlogo/fmwwev.jpg',
        title: 'WDUN_IR',
        width: '200',
        height: '200',
        skin: 'bekle',
        autostart: 'true',
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we don't support ShoutCast (http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support), but you can try this.

Under:

```
autostart: 'true',
```

Add:

```
type: 'mp3'
```